# How to protect file and folder in a portable drive?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, password-protection, document-management

I had a situation here where I often bring my laptop outside to work or make a copy of files/documents to pendrive. Just wonder is there a way to protect the files/documents in case I lost the laptop or pendrive?

The main concern is the protection on file/documents, is there a way to auto turn on the password protection in office whenever I create a new documents?  or there is a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Would [BitLocker To Go](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd490967.aspx) be a viable solution? There's also a [BitLocker To Go Reader](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/what-is-the-bitlocker-to-go-reader) for earlier operating systems (XP/Vista).

Comment: Hi, I just want to protect the files, not all the partition. Somehow I only using Win 7 Pro. Thanks